# Smarty Fatal Error call to undefine function

Tags: smarty

Experience this issue before where my site gives a fatal error. See the exact message below:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function smarty_block_actionscolumn() in /www/performance/skill/templates_c/_global_templates_skills^%%89^898^898B4BF2%%skills.tpl.php on line 680
```

Deleting the smarty templates cache fixed it but after a few days, the issue occurred again. Is there any idea what could probably be the cause of the issue? I have look into my tpl file, i couldn't find any issue with it.

Comment: This http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/issues/detail?id=83 seems to adress the same problem. Wich Smarty version are your running?

Comment: Yes, I have saw that earlier. Does anyone here, experience the same? Im using smarty 2.6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefits of others, I was able to find out the cause of the issue, the problem here was that there were missing data/information passed into plugin which make it fails to work.